# Quickly package command fails

Tags: packaging, quickly

I get an error when trying to package my quickly application:

```
$ quickly package
........Ubuntu packaging created in debian/
............An error has occurred during package building
ERROR: package command failed
Aborting
```

It doesn't really give me an indication of what went wrong. It used to work before.

If you need to take a look at the code:

```
lp:~koukin/+junk/unity-bookmarks
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that I had edited the name in setup.py to an invalid value. I just reverted this to the original name and the problem was fixed.